# NullPointerException on setLayoutParams FloatingButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to show floating button when the users selects option from the listview. On the Items selected in want to display the floating button otherwise the floating button should be hidden. Here is the code I working with

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Click action
                    ParseObject message = createMessage();
                    if (message == null) {
                        // error
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecipientsActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage(R.string.error_selecting_file)
                                .setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                    else {
                        send(message);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });   

 @Override
            protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

                if (l.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) {
                    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    p.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END;
                    p.setAnchorId(R.id.colayout);
                    fab.setLayoutParams(p);
                    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
```

Here is the layout resource file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/colayout"
    tools:context=".RecipientsActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty_recipients_list_message" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_checkbox_marked_circle_outline_white_48dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the Logcat

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.teamtreehouse.ribbit.RecipientsActivity.onListItemClick(RecipientsActivity.java:129)
                                                                              at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1214)


       at
```

Comment: your fab widget is null, please add the instantiating code for it

Comment: How do I add instantiating code?

Comment: @thepoosh I have added the code above

Comment: please share your complete activity here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate your Floating action button gloablly.
You are not instantiating it globally

You should declare `FloatingActionButton fab;` as global outside your onCreate
and then

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Click action
        ParseObject message = createMessage();
        if (message == null) {
            // error
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecipientsActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.error_selecting_file)
                    .setTitle(R.string.error_selecting_file_title)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
        else {
            send(message);
            finish();
        }
    }
});

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (l.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) {
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END;
        p.setAnchorId(R.id.colayout);
        fab.setLayoutParams(p);
        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer. Replace this line:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

with this line:

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);//remove FloatingActionButton
```

and add a global variable at the begining of your class:

```
class your_class {
    FloatingActionButton fab;//define as global variable
```

Reason: you used the local variable `fab`.

Comment: i have the same problem too, and solve it with your answer. though why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your fab widget anywhere in the code
Maybe you need to instantiate it first

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.your_fab_id);
```

**UPDATE:**
You may need to edit the way you're declaring the `LayoutParams`

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
    p.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END;
    p.setAnchorId(R.id.colayout);
    fab.setLayoutParams(p);
    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```